# finding all token addresses in a wallet

Tags: rpc, jsonrpc-api, solana.py, solana-py

im using python and the RPC API, which based on my research only has the GPA (get program accounts) in terms of getting a list of owned tokens.

how can i do this without using GPA due to its various shortcomings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used Python to interact with the Solana blockchain but for the RPC API you could use [getTokenAccountsByOwner](https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#gettokenaccountsbyowner) for getting all the token accounts but i am not sure in your question token addresses means the mint address of a token or the tokenAccount address's of the user.

You could use the various API services as well like helius and many more

Comment: I'm not sure what to pass to the opts for getTokenAccountsByOwner. would i pass the wallet that minted them? in terms of a verification system, the idea would be to pass your public key to the program and it would return a number of how many of x token you have.

Comment: you just need to pass the user's address rest are optional

Comment: No, either mint or programId is required. hence my question.

Comment: ahh sorry, you have to pass the TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID

Comment: But this will give the list of token accounts you need to do a RPC call again. this one https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#gettokenaccountbalance to get the balance or no of tokens in it

Comment: So, how do i get the token program id? hence my question.

Comment: This is the address TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA